# SQL search by column's content and let column name at first column in result table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

if I have a table, and want to search in every column's content:

```
name    col1    col2
data1   1       10
data2   2       20
data3   na      30
data4   4       na
data5   5       na
...     ...     ...
```

I want to get the table likes follow:

```
col_name    na    not_na
col1        1     4
col2        2     3
```

Is there any method to do that?
Thanks first!

Comment: I dont quite get your output.. How is the input getting transformed?

Comment: @Teja looks like the output is a count of the rows with that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to construct a `union all` query:

```
select 'col1' as column, sum(col1 = 'na') as na,
       sum(col1 is distinct from 'na') as not_na
from t
union all
select 'col2' as column, sum(col2 = 'na') as na,
       sum(col2 is distinct from 'na') as not_na
from t;
```

If you have lots of columns, you can construct such a query using a query on the metadata tables (`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`) or by using a spreadsheet.

Comment: I messed up and edited your answer instead of adding my own. Please forgive my mistake, and put your answer back in. My apologies!

Comment: @SloanThrasher . . . No harm done.  I've done that before myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a UNION.

```
(
    SELECT 'col1' as col_name,
    (SELECT COUNT(`name`) FROM `table` WHERE `col1` = 'na') as na,
    (SELECT COUNT(`name`) FROM `table` WHERE `col1` != 'na') as not_na
)
UNION
(
    SELECT 'col2' as col_name,
    (SELECT COUNT(`name`) FROM `table` WHERE `col2` = 'na') as na,
    (SELECT COUNT(`name`) FROM `table` WHERE `col2` != 'na') as not_na
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple SUM function containing an IF:

```
SELECT 
    'col1' as `col_name`,
    SUM(IF(`col1` = 'na',1,0)) as `na`,
    SUM(IF(`col1` = 'na',0,1)) as `not_na`
FROM `table`
UNION
SELECT 
    'col2' as `col_name`,
    SUM(IF(`col2` = 'na',1,0)) as `na`,
    SUM(IF(`col2` = 'na',0,1)) as `not_na`
FROM `table`;
```